When attempting to load a X509 Certificate, I get Argument Exception: Only integer can be converted
I'm trying to load a valid X509 so that I can use the function
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, clientCertificateRequired: false, checkCertificateRevocation: true);

I try to load the certificate as follows:
serverCertificate = new X509Certificate("c:/my/path/server_pfx.pfx");

However when I do, I get this error:

FormatException: Only integer can be converted
Mono.Security.ASN1Convert.ToInt32 (Mono.Security.ASN1 asn1) (at <193c77b884c54aa38915aba0dcad62fa>:0)
Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12.Decrypt (Mono.Security.PKCS7+EncryptedData ed) (at <193c77b884c54aa38915aba0dcad62fa>:0)
Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12.Decode (System.Byte[] data) (at <193c77b884c54aa38915aba0dcad62fa>:0)
Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12..ctor (System.Byte[] data, System.String password) (at <193c77b884c54aa38915aba0dcad62fa>:0)
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.ImportPkcs12 (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password) (at :0)
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.ImportPkcs12 (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password) (at :0)
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) (at :0)
Mono.X509PalImpl.ImportFallback (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) (at :0)
Mono.X509PalImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) (at :0)
Mono.SystemCertificateProvider.Import (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, Mono.CertificateImportFlags importFlags) (at :0)
Mono.SystemCertificateProvider.Mono.ISystemCertificateProvider.Import (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, Mono.CertificateImportFlags importFlags) (at :0)
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) (at :0)
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor (System.String fileName, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) (at :0)
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor (System.String fileName) (at :0)
Server.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:32)

The certificate was generated by doing:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out server_pfx.pfx -macalg sha1

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong? Or a much simpler idea, how can I generate a certificate that will work with AuthenticateAsServer function?
EDIT: I have confirmed this is a UNITY issue. If I use the exact same line of code in a dotnet application I don't get the excepetion. However I'm out of luck because there simply seems to be NO way of loading a certificate with a private key in unity.

A Pkcs12 file is not an X509 certificate. You probably need one of the X509Certificate2 constructors. About the name X509Certificate2 ... don't ask.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Or in other words: [ASN.1 DER is the only certificate format supported by this class.
For most scenarios, you should use the X509Certificate2 class instead.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate?view=net-8.0#remarks)

Changed to 2 and it is the exact same error. I knew about the 2, but I wasn't sure it was compatible with the AuthenticateAsServer function.

I got an edity that took out the Unity Part of the question. The reason it was relevant, is because the ONLY explanation that I could find as to why this (using X509 1 or 2) throws the error is BECAUSE Unity. And if this code were to be used in a regular console application it would work. I

I suggest you file a bug report if this is a valid PFX but not loading in Unity
